# Extract word by regex in python

Tags: python, regex

I'm new to Python and would like to know how to use regex.

Suppose I have a patter like

```
alice(ben)charlie(dent)elise(fiona)
```

or

```
grace
```

For the first case, I want to get `<alice,charlie,elise>`.

For the second case, I want get `grace`.

I tried below, but only got `elise(fiona), elise`

```
import re

foo = 'alice(ben)charlie(dent)elise(fiona)'
pattern = re.compile(r'((\w+)\(\w+\))+')

match = re.findall(pattern, foo)
print(match)
```

Comment: What are the pattern requirements? The examples are not clear to deduce the requirements themselves. Any word followed with an optional parenthesized substring? Or any *string*? Or a word not immediately preceded OR immediately followed with a parenthesis (as in mozway's answer)?

Comment: Have a look at https://regex101.com . That often helps me to test and modify regex patterns.

Comment: How many times do you expect the pattern `((\w+)\(\w+\))+` to match? What do you expect will be the matches? (Hint: what does the final `+` do?)

Comment: Please try to use complete English sentences to explain **what the code should do**. For example, when you say "For the first case, I want to get <alice,charlie,elise>.", **how do you know** that is the right answer for that case?

Answer (score 3):

A common beginner error is expecting a repeated capturing parenthesis to return all the captured matches with `re.findall`. It does not; as you discovered, it returns the last group after having found all the matches.

In some more detail, your regex says "find as many of this parenthesized expression as possible" and `findall` finds all of them in one iteration. At that point, the last match is what landed in the parentheses, so that's what the capturing group returns.

Simply removing the final `+` changes the behavior so that `findall` will return each match but not skip ahead, allowing the next iteration to find the next match.

```
>>> re.findall(r'((\w+)\(\w+\))', 'alice(ben)charlie(dent)elise(fiona)')
[('alice(ben)', 'alice'), ('charlie(dent)', 'charlie'), ('elise(fiona)', 'elise')]
```

Now, you are telling `findall` to find and return a single match at a time; because you are finding all of them, it will then recommence searching from where the previous match was found, and returning whatever matched in each iteration.

Depending on your corner cases, you could make the literal parentheses optional, or otherwise specify what exactly the trailing context should be.

```
>>> re.findall(r'(\w+)(?:\(\w+\))?', 'grace')
['grace']
>>> re.findall(r'(\w+)(?:\(\w+\))?', 'alice(ben)charlie(dent)elise(fiona)')
['alice', 'charlie', 'elise']
```

As you didn't actually require the entire expression to be captured, I removed the outermost capturing parentheses as well.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to capture the word(s) that are not preceded by an opening parenthesis or followed by a closing one, you can use `(?<!\()\b\w+\b(?!\))`:

```
re.findall(r'(?<!\()\b\w+\b(?!\))', 'alice(ben)charlie(dent)elise(fiona)')
# ['alice', 'charlie', 'elise']

re.findall(r'(?<!\()\b\w+\b(?!\))', 'grace')
# ['grace']

re.findall(r'(?<!\()\b\w+\b(?!\))', '(ben)charlie(dent)elise(fiona)')
# ['charlie', 'elise']
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5tCNTj/1)

```
(?<!\()\b  # match a word boundary not preceded by "("
\w+        # match word character(s)
\b(?!\))   # match a word boundary not followed by ")"
```

Comment: The crucial change is losing the final `+`, like in my answer. The other changes seem gratuitous. `\w` matches slightly different characters than `[A-Za-z]`, including underscore and numbers; whether this makes a difference to the OP's use case should at least be discussed.

Comment: My main gripe is really that this lacks any explanation as to what was wrong or why the proposed solution works.

Comment: @tripleee fair for the lack of description of "why this failed?", but for the "why the proposed answer works?" I have the feeling that I provided enough details (examples, regex demo and description of the chunks of the regex), suggestions on how to improve are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood your problem correctly and I made a regex to solve this problem :). The pattern should be something like this `(?:([a-zA-Z]+)(?:\(.+?\))?)` and the capture group id should be 1 for the names outside the parentheses. If you want to play around with the regex and understand it better use this link:

https://regexr.com/79fct

Comment: Although this is not a provided use case, this would fail on `'(ben)charlie(dent)elise(fiona)'`, incorrectly matching `'ben'`

Comment: use this instead `(?:(?:\(.+?\))?([a-zA-Z]+)(?:\(.+?\))?)` link for more info: https://regexr.com/79fft

Answer (score 0):

The final `+` on the pattern `r'((\w+)\(\w+\))+'` causes the pattern to match the entire string, once:

```
>>> re.search(pattern, foo)
<re.Match object; span=(0, 35), match='alice(ben)charlie(dent)elise(fiona)'>
```

So, the `re.findall` result has a list with single result, `('elise(fiona)', 'elise')`, which is all the `.groups` of that match:

```
>>> re.search(pattern, foo).groups()
('elise(fiona)', 'elise')
```

If we remove the `+` from the pattern, it matches only a single plain/bracketed pair:

```
>>> pattern = re.compile(r'((\w+)\(\w+\))')
>>> re.search(pattern, foo)
<re.Match object; span=(0, 10), match='alice(ben)'>
```

And `findall` will give multiple results:

```
>>> re.findall(pattern, foo)
[('alice(ben)', 'alice'), ('charlie(dent)', 'charlie'), ('elise(fiona)', 'elise')]
```

To get the results of `findall` to be plain strings, the regex needs to have at most one capturing group:

```
>>> test = 'xxxxxx'
>>> re.findall('xx', test)
['xx', 'xx', 'xx']
>>> re.findall('x(x)', test)
['x', 'x', 'x']
>>> re.findall('(x)(x)', test)
[('x', 'x'), ('x', 'x'), ('x', 'x')]
```

With no capturing groups, it shows the entire match; with one, it shows the part matched by that capturing group (for each match); with more than one, it shows a tuple of all the capturing groups' matches.

To work around this, don't use extra capturing groups. We can use non-capturing groups, but in the current case, the problem is an extra pair of parentheses that simply isn't necessary (at least now that the `+` is gone):

```
>>> pattern = re.compile(r'(\w+)\(\w+\)')
>>> re.findall(pattern, foo)
['alice', 'charlie', 'elise']
```

However, this will still not work for the second example:

```
>>> re.findall(pattern, 'grace')
[]
```

This is because, without a parenthesized name in the string, the regex **isn't matched**. Of course, we can work around that by making that part of the pattern optional - this now does require a non-capturing group:

```
>>> pattern = re.compile(r'(\w+)(?:\(\w+\))?')
>>> re.findall(pattern, foo)
['alice', 'charlie', 'elise']
>>> re.findall(pattern, 'grace')
['grace']
```

Another approach is to think about the problem completely differently: treat the parenthesized names as *separators* for data that we want to split up. Thus:

```
>>> re.split('\(\w+\)', foo)
['alice', 'charlie', 'elise', '']
>>> re.split('\(\w+\)', 'grace')
['grace']
```

This gives an extra empty string at the end in the first case - it represents all of the text in the string after the `(fiona)` match.